# How to rearrange a data in R

Tags: r, transfer

I have a long data list similar to the following one:

```
set.seed(9)
part_number<-sample(1:5,5,replace=TRUE)
Type<-sample( c("A","B","C"),5, replace=TRUE)
rank<-sample(1:20,5,replace=TRUE)
data<-data.frame(cbind(part_number,Type,rank))
data

     part_number Type rank
1           2    A    3
2           1    B    1
3           2    B   18
4           2    C    7
5           3    C   10

I want to rearrange the data in the following way: 

     part_number A  B   C
1                   1
2                3  18  7      
3                      10
```

I think I need to use the reshape library. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would go about doing the following:

```
data <- reshape(data, idvar = "part_number", timevar = "Type", direction = "wide")
data
```

To format it exactly as you asked, I would add in,

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  arrange(part_number) %>%
  dplyr::select(part_number, A = rank.A, B = rank.B, C = rank.C)
```

If you however had a lot more columns to rename, I would use the `gsub` function to rename by pattern. In addition, since now the row names are messy,

```
rownames(data) <- c()
```

Let me know if this doesn't work or this wasn't what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
libary(tidyr)
data %>% spread(Type,rank)
#   part_number    A    B    C
# 1           1 <NA>    1 <NA>
# 2           2    3   18    7
# 3           3 <NA> <NA>   10
```